# Negative a.e. right derivative implies monotonicity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for a.e. $t \in [0, 1]$ there exists the right derivative $f'_+(t)$. Suppose also that for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and for a.e. $t \in [0, 1]$ the inequality
$$
f'_+(t) = \lim_{h \to +0} \frac{f(t + h) - f(t)}{h} < - \varepsilon
$$
holds true.

Question: Is $f$ nonincreasing on $[0, 1]$?

Clearly, the answer is 'Yes' if $f$ is absolutely continuous. Moreover, in this case $f$ is strictly decreasing. However, I am mostly interested in the case when $f$ is merely continuous.